# Is undefined as response object in a Youtube javascript api client request a bug?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, undefined, response

I list videos in a playlist with the javascript client api like this:

```
var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list(options);

request.execute(function(response) {
---
```

It works fine, but sometimes response is undefined for the same query. Can response legitimately be undefined here or is it a bug?

According to this it cannot be undefined, at most false, but it should not be false, because the response should be a json object in this case:

> The callback function which executes when the request succeeds or
>   fails. jsonResp contains the response parsed as JSON. If the response
>   is not JSON, this field will be false. rawResp is the HTTP response.
>   It is JSON, and can be parsed to an object which includes body,
>   headers, status, and statusText fields.

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiclientHttpRequest

So is it an occasionally appearing bug to be fixed or should I be prepared for response being undefined here in the production app?